# Receive database changes on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, json.net, entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

My Db layer is a MySQL Db. I am using Entity Framework to grab the data from the Db and then using a WCF service I am relaying my data as JSON through my IIS server.

This data is then handled through AJAX and Knockout JS and updates my view however often I want.

My question is that if my data is coming from an external source and constantly changing, how do I get Entity Framework to see these changes and push them to my mapped entity in my WCF service?

Let me know if anything is unclear about this.

Comment: do you mean the database structure constantly changing?

Comment: No I mean the values of the data is constantly changing. I am not updating them from the view, but they are being updated by a completely separate application.

Comment: It should come through whenever there's an update in the database.

Comment: So as long as I have the data contract class for the table and its being sent to my IIS Server in JSON, those JSON values should poll automatically? I'm just wondering if there are performance restrictions on this or if I can choose when and how they update.